# Can I use a covariate in a RM-ANOVA design and can the covariate be ordinal?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, ancova, predictor

I'm having some trouble deciding what the best approach is to may data. The following is the setup of the study:

Between-subjects factor: Group (2 levels)
Within-subjects factors: Time (2 levels), Location (6 levels), Condition (2 levels)
Outcome variable: Continuous

Of my 2 groups 0% of one of them is medicated while of the other group 65% are medicated. What I'm wondering is how I can control for medication usage? I can enter the medication usage as nominal (e.g., yes or no) or ordinal (e.g., number of medications being used, which ranges from 0-7). It sounds as though there is some debate about whether covariates should be used at all in repeated measures designs so thoughts on that would be appreciated as well as any input on ways in which to control for medication usage if covariate is not the correct approach given that it is not a continuous variable.